# How to run command 'ionic run android' on specific device?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have 2 devices detected in adb. One from my genymotion, and the other from my real device :

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.57.101:5555 device
e78ab88d    device
```

I want to run my ionic app on `e78ab88d device`. How can i achieve this?
If i run `ionic run android`, its automatically run on my genymotion device. It says, no target specified.
[img no target specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE4J4.png)

What command to run on specific device?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

run with target device id, something like :

```
ionic run android --target=e78ab88d
```

**EDIT**

With new Ionic 3 CLI use :

```
ionic cordova run android --target=e78ab88d
```

For list of all available devices, use :

```
ionic cordova run android --list
```

Comment: what is that deviceID? can it be changed to a simple human readable form?

Comment: if you run `adb devices`, you see all devices. If you're the only one, that's the only entry

Comment: If you are working with just cordova you can use the same command without the `ionic` keyworkd: `cordova run android --target=e78ab88d` as in my case, it worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

try this command may help you

```
ionic run android --e78ab88d
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `--target=e78ab88d` failed for me. But it seemed to work when I used `--device=e78ab88d`.

Basically I have 2 Android phones connected and I wanted to target a specific device. without the `--target` or `--device`, it deployed randomly to the devices.

`ionic cordova run android --device=e78ab88d` worked for me. Just in case someone is experiencing the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

to also run the app live do.
$**ionic cordova run android -l**

make sure that the phone is connected with laptop through cable.