# Ionic run : launch my emulator but not the app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I use ionic 1.7.16 and cordova 6.2.0

With `adb devices -list` I have no device detected whereas my phone is plugged on my PC (with USB debug)

I have installed my java jdk, Android SDK & Ant and add them to my PATH variable.

Result of `cordova requirements` :

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed .
Android SDK: installed
Android target: installed android-23,android-24
Gradle: installed

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple OS X: not installed
Cordova tooling for iOS requires Apple OS X
Error: Some of requirements check failed
```

When I launch `ionic run android` it runs automatically my emulator, instead of installing the apk on my phone plugged. Moreover, my android emulator is launched but not my app ...

I looked for solution but I found nothing.

This method not correspond to the version of my cordova unfortunately.
["cordova launch success" but no app running on cellphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008842/cordova-launch-success-but-no-app-running-on-cellphone)

Anyone have a solution to fix my problem ?

Thank's for your answers.

Comment: Hmm make sure you have done everything on that [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925992/chrome-devtools-devices-does-not-detect-device-when-plugged-in?answertab=votes#tab-top). Maybe your OEM driver is missing.

Comment: It works now. Thank you. I think it was the adb driver which missing..

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem a while back, at the time I would just add the '--target' flag on the command and then put the ID of my phone, described here:
[How to run command 'ionic run android' on specific device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079529/how-to-run-command-ionic-run-android-on-specific-device)

In order to get my device ID I was going to my Android install to run the 'adb.exe devices', which was installed here:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Rather than go to that destination every time, I added it to my path so I could run the command anywhere. Now I realize that I no longer need the 'target' flag.
My guess is that ionic uses 'adb.exe' to find connected devices. If it doesn't know where to find adb.exe then it just launches an emulator.

So try adding the adb.exe loctation to your path variable and see if ionic will automatically deploy to your device.

Here is a description of how to add locations to your path variable:

[How to add locations to your path variable](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Drag the generated apk to the opened emulator and drop it. It will install the app.